# Table.where(x:y).othertable

Tags: ruby, activerecord, relational-database, belongs-to

Is there some way using my relational database setup with active record to get a group of `x` and find all of their `y`'s assuming that each `y` `belong_to` an `x` and each `x` `has_many` `y`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be done this way at all. You need to join the tables together lke this.

It you have a class `User` that `has_many` `Posts` then you should write `Post.joins(:user).where('users.x = ?', y)`

This way you should return all posts of users who have a certain attribute.

Comment: Great answer thanks! You get accepted if you just change to formatting to be more correct as seen in section 2.3.1 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I prefer to write it this way :D. Anyways it should be `Post.joins(:user).where(user: {x: y})`